# Getting model, it's count of associations and a single association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, left-join

I'm trying to display a number of popular collabs in an app, and also showing the number of likes (collaboration-associations where 'status' equals 2), and if the current user has liked it or not (based on the status in the collaboration-association for the requesting user).

I have these models:

```
Collab:
- has_many :collaborations

Collaboration:
- belongs_to :collab
- belongs_to :user

User:
- has_many :collaborations
```

What I want as a result of the query below, is:

An array of 10 collab-objects, where the collab-objects contains:

- The like_count of all associations where status is 2.
- And the
  collaboration-object associated with the requesting user
  (params[:user_id]). OR just the status of the collaboration-association. I only actually need the 'status'-attribute.

PS: A user can only like a collab one time, so there will only be one collaboration-association to the collab from each user.

This is what I have now. This gives me the ten collabs and the count of associations. I'm not sure on how to include only the collaboration/collaboration-attribute by the provided user_id.

```
popular_collabs = Collab
                      .left_outer_joins(:collaborations, :reports)
                      .select("collabs.*, SUM(CASE WHEN collaborations.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as like_count")
                      .where(reports: {id: nil})
                      .where("collabs.deadline >= ?", Date.today)
                      .group(:id)
                      .order('like_count DESC')
                      .limit(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Collab:
- has_many :collaborations
- has_many :users, :through => :collaborations

Collaboration:
- belongs_to :collab
- belongs_to :user

User:
- has_many :collaborations
- has_many :collabs, :through => :collaborations
```

> (How to include only the collaboration/collaboration-attribute by the
>   provided user_id.) -

```
popular_collabs = Collab
                      .left_outer_joins(:collaborations, :users, :reports)
                      .select("collabs.*, SUM(CASE WHEN collaborations.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as like_count")
                      .where(users: {id: params[:user_id]})
                      .where(reports: {id: nil})
                      .where("collabs.deadline >= ?", Date.today)
                      .group(:id)
                      .order('like_count DESC')
                      .limit(10)
```

Or

```
popular_collabs = Collab
                      .left_outer_joins(:collaborations, :reports)
                      .select("collabs.*, SUM(CASE WHEN collaborations.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as like_count")
                      .where("collaborations.user_id = ?", params[:user_id])
                      .where(reports: {id: nil})
                      .where("collabs.deadline >= ?", Date.today)
                      .group(:id)
                      .order('like_count DESC')
                      .limit(10)
```

Comment: But with this will only count max one for each collab, since the left outer join will be limited to the collaborations.user_id? I want the total likes on each collab regardless of user. I only want the status of a certain collaboration (by user_id), but the total like_count. @gabbar